# Paginate On Custom Page Template

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I do not quite understand with wordpress. Maybe this is a stupid question.

I create a Custom Page, My Blog name. All The Blog Posts entered.
I want to ask is how to create pagination like this << Pre [1] [2] [3] ... Next >> and the post number is determined from the Settings> Reading> Blog pages show at most .... post.

This is my code.

```
<div class="page-content">
  <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $args_recent_posts = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => '$paged');
    $loop_recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args_recent_posts );
      if ( $loop_recent_posts->have_posts() ) :
        function the_excerpt_max_charlength($charlength)
          {
            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            $charlength++;

            if ( strlen( $excerpt ) > $charlength )
              {
                $subex = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $charlength - 5 );
                $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
                $excut = - ( strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );

            if ( $excut < 0 )
              {
                 echo mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
              }
            else
              {
                echo $subex;
              }
                echo '...';
              }
            else
              {
                echo $excerpt;
              }
          }  
      while ( $loop_recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $loop_recent_posts->the_post();
  ?>
  <div class="entry-item">
    <div class="entry-image-col1">
      <div class="ch-item chi-mg">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'page-image-1' ); } ?>
        <div class="ch-info"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="detail">See Full Post</a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry-info-col1">
      <div class="entry-meta">
        <div class="entry-date">
          <?php the_time('j M'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="entry-author">Author : <span>
          <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
          </span></div>
        <span class="entry-comment">Comment : <span>
        <?php comments_number( 'no', 'one', '%' ); ?>
        </span></span> </div>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a></div>
        <p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,250); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link"><?php echo __( 'Read More &raquo;'); ?></a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft">
      <?php next_posts_link('« Older Entries') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="alignright">
      <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries »') ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone helps me.
Thank you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use [WP Paginate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/) - it's incredibly easy to use.

Comment: Whoever marked me down would you please explain why?